# Android Studio errors: public inline operator fun BigInteger.times(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, multiplication, biginteger

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.div(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline operator fun BigInteger.div(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x30NF.jpg)

This works in IntelliJ IDEA, but not in Android Studio. Why? This is usually multiplication.

Thank you!

Comment: `x.toInt()` is a function that returns an Int, but it cannot and does not change what the type of the variable x is. You are getting an Int and doing nothing with it so the value is thrown away. `x` is still the String that you got from the EditText. You need to assign the result of `x.toInt()` to another variable and then you can use that in your math.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and good answer !!!